# What happened on my `Enumerable.Range(,)`?

Tags: c#, linq, indexoutofboundsexception

What happened on my `Enumerable.Range(,)`?
It produced a number 5030 which is out of range.

`sellableItems` is a small `List<T>`,  I need to randomly pick 9 items from it.

Here is the code:

```
var targetIndexes = Enumerable.Range(i + 1, sellableItems.Count-1)
      .OrderBy(x => random.Next())
      .Take(9)
      .ToArray();

for (var j = 0; j < targetIndexes.Length; j++)
{
     ...
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the `i`?

Comment: I'm guessing `i == 30`? The second argument to `Enumerable.Range()` is a count, not an end index

Comment: The 2nd parameter is Count so you are asking to start at 36 and add 5000 which is giving a range of 36 : 5036.

Comment: just change it to `Range(i + 1, sellableItems.Count - i - 1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Enumerable.Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?view=netframework-4.8) method takes in two parameters - a starting value and a count.

When you do: `Enumerable.Range(i + 1, sellableItems.Count - 1)`, you are starting with the value `37` (`i + 1`) and a count of `4999` (`sellableItems.Count - 1`).

Since each iteration in the call to `Range` increments the previous value by one (except the first iteration, which uses the starting value), the range will be from `37` to `5035`.

Comment: LOL, so it should be: `Enumerable.Range(i + 1, sellableItems.Count - i - 1)`. I touched a G point mistakenly. Thanks your patience.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "pain point". What is the range you want to use?

Comment: I guess so, but why do you add one to `i`? Are you trying to exclude the first (`0`) index? In a collection with three items, `Enumerable.Range(0, 3)` (where start is the first index and count is the array length) will return all the indexes.